# Why does a Realm's schema version reset to 0 after a migration?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to perform a Realm migration with the following code:

```
let version = try! schemaVersionAtURL(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
let config = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: version + 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: MyObject.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                        // Here I transfer existing data to new properties
                    }
                }
        })
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
let _ = try! Realm()
```

The migration seems to work fine, but the next time the app is relaunched, both the current and old schema versions are 0, despite having been set to 1 by the migration that occurred during the first launch.

But the migration is done, so the `if` condition is true, and the app crashes with a Realm exception caused by trying to perform the migration again.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing? If the configuration is setting the schema version to 1 during the migration, why is it 0 the next time the app is relaunched?

Comment: After migration, do you delete the app and reinstall it?

Comment: @A.Munzer if he did that would set the migration to 0 , however if he not,  i don't think he is getting the right version in the first place.

Comment: @MohmmadS, figure out the problem, he forget to delete old realm schema.

Comment: @A.Munzer Why would he ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was actually calling Realm before the migration was performed. I'd forgotten a bit of code I had running in `willFinishingLaunchingWithOptions` that called it.

Lesson Learned: **Only the very first call to Realm performs the migration.**

Answer (score 0):

> The migration seems to work fine, but the next time the app is
>   relaunched, both the current and old schema versions are 0,

This is caused when you delete the local `Realm` file and reinstall it, usually occur when you delete and reinstall the application,

`Realm` handles migrations automatically all it need to know if there was a new version number that would cause the file to rewrite it self with the new rules.

---

Now for the crashing part, you are using this, an issue  with an *open* stat on [github](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5861#issue-343682922)

```
let version = try! schemaVersionAtURL(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

However i agree with [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5861#issuecomment-407196617) comment.

> I guess there's two issues here:
>
> 1- It sounds like `schemaVersionAtURL()` is creating an empty file if given
>   a URL for a file that doesn't exist, and it obviously shouldn't be
>   doing that.
>   2- In Swift `schemaVersionAtURL()` should be `UInt64?` and just
>   return nil if the file doesn't exist rather than throwing

I recommend using plain `Int` for version rather than getting it from the file, 
as it shows in `Realm` [documents](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), `schemaVersion: 1`, and increment it manually this will let you always see what version number you are on and when it crashes you know you did something worthy a migration.

Now for the part where you say.

> both the current and old schema versions are 0

When you reinstall your application it simply recreate the file with version 0 because the new rules your code implemented to `Realm` its just simple new file so setting schema version to lower in code would not do pretty much, however this is not recommended because when you go live people will not reinstall the application they will update it, therefore a `Realm` file is migrated to upper version, however the new users downloading the application with version number `0`, so think about it more as a change need to be made  *rather than an increment number only bigger is better*.

Comment: More as could be an open issue or he is using it wrongly because testing with realm have various cases such as app deleted , app need migration etc

Comment: So if he set the schema statically to 1, his issue will be solved.

Comment: his issue is not the number needed to be set more than what is happening, the number of his version is him deciding the right one, i just explain what is probably happening with him.